# How to improve slow query with indexed tables MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This query takes on average 2/3 seconds. Every fields in join and where are indexes.

How I can improve this query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT pro_id, pro_url, pro_data, pro_capa, pro_destaque, pro_destaque_data, pro_nome, pro_likes, pro_views, pro_comentarios_total, pro_autor FROM projeto JOIN utilizador_projeto ON pro_id=utp_proid JOIN utilizador ON utp_utiid=uti_id WHERE pro_activo=1 AND pro_privacidade=1 ORDER BY pro_destaque_data DESC LIMIT 24;
```

slow_query_log:

```
# Time: 190923  1:10:58
# User@Host: root[root] @  [10.133.247.241]
# Thread_id: 36  Schema: db  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 3.575462  Lock_time: 0.000114  Rows_sent: 24  Rows_examined: 104820
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 3974

MariaDB [db]> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT pro_id, pro_url, pro_data, pro_capa, pro_destaque, pro_destaque_data, pro_nome, pro_likes, pro_views, pro_comentarios_total, pro_autor FROM projeto JOIN utilizador_projeto ON pro_id=utp_proid JOIN utilizador ON utp_utiid=uti_id WHERE pro_activo=1 AND pro_privacidade=1 ORDER BY pro_destaque_data DESC LIMIT 24;
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                                                                                 | key                 | key_len | ref                             | rows  | Extra                        |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | projeto            | ref    | PRIMARY,pro_destaques_index,pro_likes_index,pro_comments_index,pro_views_index,pro_date_index | pro_destaques_index | 2       | const,const                     | 17865 | Using where; Using temporary |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | utilizador_projeto | ref    | utp_utiid,utp_proid                                                                           | utp_proid           | 4       | db.projeto.pro_id               |     1 | Distinct                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | utilizador         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY             | 4       | db.utilizador_projeto.utp_utiid |     1 | Using index; Distinct        |
+------+-------------+--------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: without information about indexes of the tables, and without the explain plan, nothing can be said about performance of the query.

Comment: Updated with the explain plan.

Comment: 1) How did pro_likes get listed in the EXPLAIN when it is not referenced in the query posted? 2) Each table listed in the EXPLAIN means we need to see TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each of the tables. 3) please post TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; for each of the tables listed in the EXPLAIN so we can see the cardinality of each column that is indexed.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for notice. I updated to the original query. Please let me know if is possible to improve it a little more.

Comment: @NAG I can not see in your question:  2) Each table listed in the EXPLAIN means we need to see TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each of the tables. 3) please post TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; for each of the tables listed in the EXPLAIN so we can see the cardinality of each column that is indexed.  For additional assistance post the requested SCTable and SIFrom from your system. Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    WHERE  pro_active=1
      AND  pro_privacy=1
    ORDER BY  pro_highlight_date DESC
```

begs for this 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(pro_active, pro_privacy,   -- in either order
      pro_highlight_date)
```

Probably `Rows_examined: 139482` will drop to `Rows_examined: 24`.

That assumes those 3 columns are in the same table.  Instead of prefixing column names with table names, do the following:

```
...
FROM project AS pro
...
WHERE pro.active = 1 ...
```

That eliminates any ambiguity (and takes about the same number of keystrokes).

> Every fields in join and where are indexes

Overkill.  And single-column indexes are often not as useful as multi-column (composite) indexes.  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: I think the third column in the index is `pro_highlight_date`, not `pro_highlight`. Maybe a typo..